# Error in my CFQUERYPARAM

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, cfquery, cfqueryparam

I'm sure I'm just doing this horribly wrong with CFQUERYPARAM, but here's what I'm trying to do:

```
<CFQUERY DATASOURCE="tr3" NAME="qryPartner">
  SELECT *
  FROM  UsrMatchActualTR2
  WHERE 
    session = #userSess# 
   AND 
    user_id = #userID# 
   AND 
    site=<cfqueryparam value="#userSite#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" maxlength="5">
</CFQUERY>
```

And I'm receiving the error

> Error Executing Database Query.
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right   syntax to use near 'AND site='UTD'' at line 3

Comment: The "site" db variable is a VARCHAR length of 4.

Comment: Well then your `maxlength` in the `cfqueryparam` should be "4", but that's not what's causing this particular error.

Comment: What are the actual values of all three (3) variables when the error occurs? Also, what are the column data types?

Comment: @Anthony simplify the problem by eliminating variables (temporarily) until the crash goes away.  Then add the variables back into the mix, using cfdump and cfabort to help with analysis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect your userID variable is blank, causing a "hole" in your query structure.  You should really use CFQUERYPARAM for all of your arguments, including userID and userSess.

Comment: The userID and the userSess are not blank variables. I tried  using cfqueryparams for all the arguments, and the same error was popping up.

Comment: I'm not convinced that my answer is incorrect, yet.  Try reordering the conditions in the where clause, and seeing if you still get the error related to the same one (`AND site` or something else).

Comment: You are not convinced because you are correct. The variable for userID wasn't being stored correctly. Curse you sleep deprivation!

Answer (score 2):

First, make sure your datatypes are correct, is the site column a varchar / string?  Also, try to use cfqueryparam for all variables.

```
<CFQUERY DATASOURCE="tr3" NAME="qryPartner">
    SELECT * FROM  UsrMatchActualTR2
    WHERE session = <cfqueryparam value="#userSess#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" />
    AND user_id = <cfqueryparam value="#userID#"  cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" />
    AND site = <cfqueryparam value="#userSite#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" maxlength="5" />
</CFQUERY>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing the "double quotes" around the value param

```
WHERE session = #userSess# AND user_id = #userID# AND site=<cfqueryparam  value="#userSite#"  cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" maxlength="5">
```

with 'single quotes'

```
WHERE session = #userSess# AND user_id = #userID# AND site=<cfqueryparam value='#userSite#'  cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" maxlength="5">
```

I have seen CF differentiate. Also, you should use `<cfqueryparam>` for all of your variables.  If you still have trouble, try   to evaluate what is stored in the variables userSess, userID and site using `<cfdump> and <cfabort>`